# JSX Fragment syntax generates "Element type is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to use JSX Fragment syntax with Typescript but I have the following error :

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol

I am using :

- React 16.2.0
- React-dom 16.2.0
- Typescript 2.6.2

Even if I use reacts code example, it fails :

```
public render() {
        return (
            <>
            Some text.
            <h2>A heading</h2>
            More text.
            <h2>Another heading</h2>
            Even more text.
          </>
        );
    }
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["webpack-env"]
  },
  "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "node_modules",
      "app/__tests__"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using full syntax (`<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`)?

Comment: First, have you tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`? Perhaps your TS install is behind what you think (this feature only became available in TS 2.6.2, so if you're even slightly behind, it'll be a problem). Second, if that doesn't work, can you please share your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @kfazi yes and it does not work. I've the same error

Comment: @JonnyAsmar I tried rm -rf... and it does not work. I've checked in node_modules and I am using ts 2.6.2 with react & react-dom 16.2.0

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the Typescript in `node_modules`? It is possible that you are executing Typescript from the global `node_modules`. Try upgrading Typescript globally with `npm install -g typescript@2.6.2` Nothing stands out in your `tsconfig.json`. I tested your options on a standard build and they all seem to work.

Comment: @JonnyAsmar Still have the same error. I am using webpack with awesome-typescript-loader, could the error comes from at-loader?

Comment: The problem definitely in the react or react-dom, can you check it? Can you attach your files, I can take a look for them

Comment: I found the issue. I am using .dotnet core react/redux template and the vendor.js bundle was not updated to react 16.2... After building a new vendor.js bundle it worked!