# React Fragment results in Element Type is Invalid Error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript2.6

I am encountering this error when attempting to use Fragments with React / Typescript with Visual Studio 2017:

**NodeInvocationException:** Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.

**Stack:**

- react 16.3
- react-dom 16.3
- typescript 2.6.2

I am also testing with sample code:

```
public render() {
        return (
            <>
            Some text.
            <h2>A heading</h2>
            More text.
            <h2>Another heading</h2>
            Even more text.
          </>
        );
    }
```

I found similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235692/jsx-fragment-syntax-generates-element-type-is-invalid). In his last comments Stephen Muhr says he updated his vendor.js bundle to get it to work without providing much details. From his comments, it sounds like he had an issue with upgrading to react 16.2. However, for me, I can verify that react 16.3 is running successfully (I output react version at runtime). So, it may not resolve my issue. I could not add to comments on that question since I am a new user.

Since the error is a server side error, I am thinking I am missing a configuration specifying the correct version of typescript. I used npm install typescript@2.6.2 and it exists in the node_modules folder. I also downloaded the TypeScript SDK for 2.6.2 and installed it. I've also set the project properties to Typescript 2.6 (and have also tried 'use latest'). None of these have worked.

I can not figure out how to output the typescript version being used at run-time.

**EDIT**
The following returned different versions of typescript on my machine:
 - **tsc -v** yields 2.3.5. 
 - **npm ls -g typescript** yields 2.6.2. 
 - **npm ls typescript** yields 2.6.2.

So, it looks like tsc -v is out of date but I have no idea how to update it.

If anyone can offer any suggestions as to what may be causing this error, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you are mentioning that your global `tsc` is at version 2.3.5. Fragment is supported from 2.6 as you mentioned.

You can update your `tsc` at the global scope by using `npm install -g typescript@2.6.2`. However, if you are running the command from the Visual Studio command prompt then it will get the `tsc` from the SDK folder. TypeScript should be installed in: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`.

If you are using a .csproj. you can also look at your project file and see the version of TypeScript, it will be under `TypeScriptToolsVersion`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have installed globally via **npm install -g typescript@2.6.2**. I checked the folder c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript. I see there are folders for 1.8, 2.3, and **2.6**. So, it appears the SDK installed correctly.